# post Json in iframe through javascript

Tags: javascript, post, iframe

I am creating and setting an invisible iframe as in the example http://encosia.com/ajax-file-downloads-and-iframes/
I have a json string to pass(POST) on submit of this frame url.
how can this be done?

Comment: I'm just throwing here some suggestion: You can avoid all iframes and forms and use pure ajax to upload files with `xhr2`. It works on most modern browsers (FF,chrome & IE 10+). For more info check out here http://www.alexanderschnitzler.de/2011/06/howto-build-an-html5-file-uploader-with-ajax/

Comment: The functionality I am working on is export to excel. currently I am using ajax. I am posting a json from front end and creating excel file. But using ajax the download pop-up is not coming. Thats why I changed to this approach.